# Add additional actions when clicking onFacebook Share button

Tags: facebook, share

Is it possible to add an additional action (for example  - alert("Thank you for share")) after user has clicked on share button on my web page.

I've found some solution here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

But if I use this, at the bottom wrote: via + NAME OF APPLICATION

Can I do it without this text at the bottom?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "via + NAME OF APPLICATION" is something that can not be changed.  The user needs to know that this post originated from that application.  You can not remove it... 
With regard to a callback - you can use it like this :

```
// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};


FB.ui(obj, function(){
   // Here you can put your code to be executed after the user publishes his/her post.
});
```